# Pandas iterative imputation without using 'for' loop

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataset, I must insert the last winner of each tennis confrontation if there is one.

| player_1 | player_2 | winner | last_winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Federer | Nadal | Federer |  |
| Djoko | Federer | Djoko |  |
| Nadal | Federer | Nadal |  |
| Djoko | Federer | Federer |  |
| Murray | Djoko | Murray |  |
| Djoko | Federer | Djoko |  |

Then it should look like this :

| player_1 | player_2 | winner | last_winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Federer | Nadal | Federer | none |
| Djoko | Federer | Djoko | none |
| Nadal | Federer | Nadal | Federer |
| Djoko | Federer | Federer | Djoko |
| Murray | Djoko | Murray | none |
| Djoko | Federer | Djoko | Federer |

This is the code I use with a for loop :

```
for i,j in tennis.iterrows() :
    
    try :
        tennis.loc[i, 'last_winner'] = tennis.iloc[:i].loc[(tennis.player_1.isin([j.player_1, j.player_2]) & tennis.player_2.isin([j.player_1, j.player_2])), "winner"].iloc[-1]
    except:
        tennis.loc[i, 'last_winner'] = "none"
```

Is there any mean to perform the same operation without any for loop, using something like an apply function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single line of code:

```
df["last_winner"] = df.groupby(
    pd.Series(
        df[["player_1", "player_2"]].values.tolist()) \
        .apply(sorted).astype(str)) \
    ["winner"].shift()
```

This can be split up into sections:

1. Create a list for each row of players 1 and 2 (as a `pd.Series`)
2. Sort this list so that all rows will match (i.e. doesn't matter if players are 1 or 2 always)
3. Turn the lists into strings for the groupby
4. `Groupby` this series
5. Take the `"winner"` column for each group and `shift`.
6. Make this a new column of the DataFrame.